# ExtJS Background image from API

Tags: image, extjs

How could I display an image in ExtJS downloaded from our API?
At the moment we are using XTemplate or HTML  for pdf documents but this makes a call in our API without the Authorization header.

I need to do it using XHRRequest or Ajax to be able to include to authorization token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Ext.Img and append the token to the url:

```
var wrappedImage = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
   src: 'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-html5.png?token=YOUR_TOKEN',
   autoEl: 'div', // wrap in a div
   renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```